# Adding values to XML instead of Overwriting it (XML + VB.NET)

Tags: xml, windows, vb.net, windows-mobile

I am having some troubles with a project of mine. Its a basic financial manager for windows mobile 5 using VB.net. Everything works fine, however, when a value is saved in xml, it will be overwritten when another is saved. I want it to add these values instead of overwriting them entirely.

My Code:

```
    Private Sub MenuItem3_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem3.Click
    Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter("product.xml", Nothing)
    writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    writer.Indentation = 2
    writer.WriteStartElement("Table")
    createNode(DateTimePicker.Text, Subject.Text, Category.Text, Amount.Text, PaymentLabel.Text, writer)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteEndDocument()
    writer.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub createNode(ByVal eDate As String, ByVal eSubject As String, ByVal eCategory As String, ByVal eAmount As String, ByVal ePayment As String, ByVal writer As XmlTextWriter)
    writer.WriteStartElement("Expenses")
    writer.WriteStartElement("Date")
    writer.WriteString(eDate)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteStartElement("Subject")
    writer.WriteString(eSubject)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteStartElement("Category")
    writer.WriteString(eCategory)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteStartElement("Amount")
    writer.WriteString(eAmount)
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteStartElement("Payment")
    writer.WriteString(ePayment)
    writer.WriteEndDocument()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to work with `XmlTextReader`, `XmlTextWriter` and, most importantly, `XmlDocument`, `XmlElement` and more.

Working with `XmlDocument`, you'll be manipulating the document using the [Document Object Model](http://www.w3.org/DOM/), which allows you to remove, insert and append XML nodes, etc.

See [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317662) for some pointers on reading/writing XML this way.
See the official documentation on [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and the [System.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3y47afh.aspx) namespace on how to manipulate documents.

Comment: Thank you Torious. Is there a different method to this? I am quite new to vb.net and this is done to complete my class project. XML is out of the topic but I wanted to display the data in grid view, as when the data are listed in the list box, there is no way we could scroll horizontally.

Comment: Yeah you can probably also use an XmlTextReader to read elements, and write them out right away using XmlTextWriter, and when you go the Table element, insert your new elements or so. But I'd really recommend using the DOM; it's not that hard, really! :)

Comment: I see. I just don't know where to start if i were to use DOM. I tried following tutorials online but none worked. Perhaps its because they're for vb.net for windows whereas I am trying it for windows mobile. This is perhaps why I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how about something like this?

```
Private Sub MenuItem3_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem3.Click

    Dim doc as New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml("product.xml")

    Dim root as XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
    Dim list as XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("Table")
    Dim table as XmlNode = list.Item(0)

    table.AppendChild(createNode(doc, ... , ... ))

    Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(Console.Out)
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    doc.WriteTo(writer)
    writer.Flush()

End Sub

Function createNode(XmlDocument doc, ByVal eDate As String, ByVal eSubject As String, ByVal eCategory As String, ByVal eAmount As String, ByVal ePayment As String, ByVal writer As XmlTextWriter) As XmlNode

    Dim element as XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Expenses")

    Dim dateElement as XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Date")
    dateElement.InnerText = eDate
    element.AppendChild(dateElement)

    ... similar code for the other sub-elements ...

    Return element

End Function
```